# Open URL from Cygwin/POSIX?

Tags: c, url, cygwin, posix

I'm writing a cygwin program that should open a web link. This code doesn't work:

```
     system("cygstart \"http://www.mysite.com\"");
```

Cygstart works from the command line but not inside the system(). 
How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

you may have to refer to the cygstart command by its full path.  e.g.:

```
system("/usr/bin/cygstart.exe \"http://www.mysite.com\"");
```

edit: you may even have to use the full windows path instead of the cygwin path.

Comment: I actually want to create a program that should not require the full cygwin environment, just the cygwin dll

Comment: @michelemarcon `cygstart.exe` is an external program which is not included in the Cygwin DLL. The `cygstart` command you enter in the shell is simply an alias for the `cygstart.exe` program; therefore, you cannot execute `cygstart` solely within the Cygwin DLL, but must call the external `cygstart.exe` included with the full cygwin environment.